# Access to both Experience Profile and Presentation Details

Tags: experience-editor, content-editor, presentation, security, experience-profile

I have a user that needs access to both Experience Profile and Presentation Details. We found a Sitecore KB reference (https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/820320) that stated if a user had the Author or Designer permissions assigned, they couldn't see the Experience Profile. This appears accurate, as my user - when they had those permissions - would click Experience Profile and be bounced to the login page. If I take away Author/Designer, they can access the Experience Profile, but then trying to access presentation details in either Content or Experience Editors is not available (they can still edit content, but not presentation).

Beyond assigning the user full admin rights, does anyone have experience with this setup? Or is this a case where they might need an analytics user account separate from their authoring account? They use AD integration, but I could create a sitecore domain user for it, I'd rather not have to go that route though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another option - define your own user access role - `sitecore/YourOwnUserRole` - then give that user all the same access as a `sitecore/Author` and `sitecore/Designer` and then make sure they have access in the core database to:

- `/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceProfile`
- `/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceAnalytics`

ref: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/820320

Comment: We are using our own groups, but I think all of us here missed that third line item. I'll take a look at it, if it works out I'll check this answer off. Thanks.